# check if the numbers belong to the same cluster

Tags: probability

I would like to find if the particular two numbers in a vector belong to the same or different groups,

For instance, I have a set of vector data: $$d_1=\{100, 120, 104, 110, 20, 25, 30, 35\}$$ I want to know whether $100$ and $35$ belong to the same group or not.

By just looking at this, it is found that this set of data can generally be clustered into 2 groups $g_1=\{100,120,104,110\}$ and $g_2=\{20,25,30,35\}$, thus the probability that $100$ and $35$ belong to the same group is lower as compared to another example: $$d_2=\{100 ,90, 80, 65, 60 ,50 ,40 ,35\}$$
This set doesn't have a clear cut between the numbers (they decrease gradually).

Is there a formula to calculate the 'score' (e.g.: $s$ for $d_2$ is higher (near to 1), as $100$ and $35$ belong to the same group and vice-versa) based on the examples given?

I thought of utilizing the mean and standard deviation, such as

$$a(d)= \left( \left(\frac{100+35}{2}\right)- \frac{\mbox{mean}(d)}{\mbox{std}(d)} \right)$$
and
$$s(d)=\exp(-c\times a(d))$$

where $c$ is a constant. But I am not sure if this is a valid way of computing it, does it make sense? Please advise. Or is there any better way to model the function?

Comment: Is there a plausible distribution for these numbers? Are they counts? What numbers are considered "similar"? Is Euclidean distance a proper metric?

Comment: The set of numbers can be made up by any random numbers (d(1) can be 100, 4, 120, 110, 5, 6, 101, 3, which too can be roughly divided into 2 clusters; and d(2) can be 100, 10, 20, 50, 80, 40, 30, 3). The 2 numbers that I want to check will always be the first and last in the set. The purpose of generating the 'score' is to identify the relationship between the two numbers in the sets, d(i). In d2, 100 and 3 are considered closer to each other because the data in d2 has a more 'balance' distribution as compared to d1.

Comment: I am still not sure what kind of distributions these are. You are always testing for 2 numbers? Are the sets always the same size? They are always whole numbers? Do you consider d(1) to be bimodal, and d(2) be unimodal somehow?